# How to hide open dialog box while writing pdf file in .net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using following to create pdf document in c#.net

```
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"; //"application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-length", stream.Length.ToString());
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + string.Format("d:\\members-{0}.pdf", string.Format("{0:ddMMyyyy}", DateTime.Today)));
    Response.ContentEncoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(); 
    Response.BinaryWrite(stream.ToArray());
    Response.Flush();
    stream.Close();
    Response.End();
```

note: stream is the my content which i want to write

Issue : Always dialog box is opening, its asked me to save all the times. I want to hide this dialog box and save the file wherever required. Please help me